# How to harden electronics to protect it from EMP(Electromagnetic pulse)?

Tags: security

My question is about hardening electronics against EMP, Electromagnetic pulse (e.g. from Nuclear burst).

I'm looking for civil solution. For electronics, that not build properly against EMP, like e.g. military radar systems.

For example, Is there way to hard civil satellite antenna against such pulse (e.g. against lightning). Without rebuild inner circuit.

Comment: You are unlikely to have access to the source materials required to build a faraday cage with the capability to protect it from a nuclear burst.  Very little is known about the pratical requirements since there have only been two, I doubt even military systems, could withstand an actual nuclear blast.

Comment: There have been considerably more than two nuclear explosions.

Comment: @Ramhound there has only been two tactical nukes used offensively. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_weapons_testing Over 2,000 KNOWN testing of nuclear weapons.

Comment: Each of this tests are monitored by kind of military electronic around a half of century.

Comment: what about testing before those worldwide monitoring stations were developed. Or low yield tests before those monitoring stations were improved (or even now). Testing of under 1 kiloton can still be done without detection.

Comment: Book on this very subject [Protection of Electronic Circuits from Overvoltages](http://books.google.com/books?id=5-NEmE1EhYQC&lpg=PR1&dq=protecting%20against%20high%20voltage%20transients%20book&pg=PA4#v=onepage&q=protecting%20against%20high%20voltage%20transients%20book&f=false).  The title doesn't mention nukes, but p.4 summarizes the threats that the book deals with.  Nuclear EMP is first on the list.

Comment: I think that your question is very under-stated. What do you want to protect, actually? The antenna from being melted by the A-bomb? The wires conneted to the antenna? The electronics which directly drive the antenna (very close to the antenna)? The computers in charge of everything, several km / miles away? The solutions are different for each. Also, how do you define "protection? That nothings gets melted, burned, damaged? Or that the communication can still go on in the middle of problems? Or that the people which happen to be near the antenna (or wires) are also safe?

Answer (score 7):

Build a [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) around the device.

Comment: agreed. physical shielding is the only real way to deal with an EM discharge.

Comment: I suggested this to his other 2 questions.

Comment: I'm apologize, but this Faraday with his cage sound like "tin foil hat".Does anyone ever use it? Does anybody see such cage with working electronics inside? I'm afraid to move magnets around my HDD, just for seconds, cause it damage data and i never seen electronics/PC inside any electro-magnetic / Faraday cage.

Comment: @woodstack Did you bother to look up what a Faraday Cage is?: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage

Comment: The problem is that by definition if the Faraday cage is functional, the computer cannot be on the internet or communicating with any other computer that is not in the same cage. This makes the computer useless for pretty much anything that a computer is used for these days.

Comment: @woodstack Yes, of course I've seen Faraday cages in use. They're vital in laboratories with sensitive electronic equipment. This is actual science, not paranoia.

Comment: FWIW, the casing on your desktop PC (and most other electronics) is actually a partial faraday cage. It keeps a lot of the RF eminations from the PC in, and garbage from the outside out. There *are* feedthroughs (i.e. all the relevant connections), but they are generally better protected then the bare electronics inside the case (e.g. ESD diodes, clamping, etc...).

Comment: @EBGreen: "The problem is that by definition if the Faraday cage is functional, the computer cannot be on the internet or communicating with any other computer that is not in the same cage" - this is not necessarily true, if you use the optical fiber connection.

Comment: Putting a Faraday cage around a satellite antenna sort of defeats the point of an antenna.

Comment: Time for a new question??? Adding on to an 8 year old question seems kind of pointless.